# Workflow Custom Action Error

Tags: workflow, custom-actions

I wrote a quick custom action for SharePoint Designer workflow. SPD recognizes the action and lets me add it, and specify my variables. When I go to publish it I receive errors

```
(0, 0) Type System.Workflow.Activities.SequenceActivity, System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.)
(0, 0) Type System.Workflow.Activities.HandleExternalEventActivity, System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.)
```

I've added them manually to the authorizedTypes element in the web.config file. My class is also there. Everything i've read online doesn't state I need to add these classes, i'm guessing I still don't have to but I tried it anyway and still didnt work, so they're removed. My authorized types are below.

```
 <System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
<authorizedTypes>
  <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ConditionedActivityGroup" Authorized="False" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ReplicatorActivity" Authorized="False" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Runtime, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.Runtime" TypeName="CorrelationToken" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Guid" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="DateTime" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Boolean" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Double" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="String" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="Hashtable" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="ArrayList" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Diagnostics" TypeName="DebuggableAttribute" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="CompilationRelaxationsAttribute" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Int32" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="TimeSpan" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections.ObjectModel" TypeName="Collection`1" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowActivationProperties" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowTaskProperties" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowHistoryEventType" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPItemKey" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowUserContext" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Macro.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Quickflow.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="ActivityLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4893c5f8f26d2c42" Namespace="ActivityLibrary1" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
</authorizedTypes>
<authorizedRuleTypes>
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Quickflow.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" TypeName="WorkflowCodeTypeReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
  <authorizedType Assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="ExtensionAttribute" Authorized="True" />
</authorizedRuleTypes>
```

and my actions file is here

```
  <WorkflowInfo>
      <Actions Sequential="then" Parallel="and">
        <Action Name="First Workflow Action"
            ClassName="ActivityLibrary1.ACoolActivity"
            Assembly="ActivityLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0,
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4893c5f8f26d2c42"
            AppliesTo="all"
            Category="Lozzi">
          <RuleDesigner Sentence="Get item count from %1 and save to %2">
            <FieldBind Field="ListValue" Text="List Name"
               DesignerType="TextArea" Id="1"/>
            <FieldBind Field="ItemsCount" Text="variable" 
                       DesignerType="ParameterNames" Id="2"/>
          </RuleDesigner>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="ListValue" Type="System.String, mscorlib"
          Direction="In" />
            <Parameter Name="ItemsCount" Type="System.Int32, mscorlib"
          Direction="Out" />
          </Parameters>
        </Action>
      </Actions>
    </WorkflowInfo>
```

and pointers or help?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, after looking at another server, I saw that I was missing

in my authorizedTypes list. Not sure why it's missing. The other two which are set to false are set to false on the other server as well.

Thanks all